# Infinite Sets and Natural Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, infinite-groups

Is it possible to find two infinite sets of non-negative integers, $A,B$, such that every non-negative integer can be written uniquely as a sum of two integers, one from $A$ and the other from $B$?

It is easy to do this if we let one set be finite.  For example, take $A=\{0,1\}$ and let $B$ be the set of non-negative even integers.  Can it be done with two infinite sets?

Remark:  the assumptions imply that $A\cap B=\{0\}$.  Indeed, the only way to write $0$ as the sum of two non-negative integers is $0=0+0$ so $0$ must be in both.  But then, if we had a non-zero $n\in A\cap B$, we could then write $n=n+0=0+n$, contradicting the uniqueness of the decomposition.

Comment: If every natural number is a sum of two elements from $A$ and $B$, then $A$ or $B$ must be infinite. Do I miss something ?

Comment: @Peter Is it possible for both sets, not just one of them, to be infinite?

Comment: To commenters: the question is about *both* $A$ and $B$ being infinite.

Comment: The question seems clear to me.  "Can you find two infinite sets of non-negative integers such that every non-negative integer can be written as a sum of two elements, one from each set, in a unique way."  It is easy to do this if you let one set be finite.  Not clear that you can do it with two infinite sets.  Good question.

Comment: The formulation is easy to misunderstand. It should better be formulated something like "Assume you've got two sets $A$, $B$ such that …"

Comment: @Stepanich02  given the confusion in the comments, I have edited your post for clarity.  Please check to make sure I did not change your meaning.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take the decomposition in base $2$ (or your favourite number), any $n \geq 0$ can be written in an unique way as $\sum_{k=0}^{m} a_k 2^k$. Now separate between odd and even powers, $$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor} a_{2k} 2^{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{m-1}{2} \rfloor} a_{2k+1} 2^{2k+1}$$

Take $A$ to be the integers that are the sum of even powers of $2$ (and $0$), and $B$ the ones of odd powers (and $0$), ie
$$ A = \{ \sum_{k=0}^m a_k 2^{2k} \mid m \geq 0, (a_0,\ldots,a_m) \in \{0,1\}^{m+1} \} \cup \{0\}$$
$$ B = \{ \sum_{k=0}^m a_k 2^{2k+1} \mid m \geq 0, (a_0,\ldots,a_m) \in \{0,1\}^{m+1} \} \cup \{0\}$$

Then surely $A \cap B = \{ 0 \}$, any $n \geq 0$ can be written as an element of $A + B$ and this sum is unique because decomposition in base $2$ is.

Comment: Congratulations. I tried to disprove the claim because I thought it is false. Now I know why this could not work. (+1). But your proof cannot be made in another base, it must be base $2$.

Comment: @Peter, not necessarily, you can take base 10 for example. The only difference is that your coordinates can now range from $0$ to $9$, but you can still decompose a number between its "even coordinates" and "odd coordinates", for example $12345 = 10305 + 2040$. Now $A$ would be $ \{ \sum_{k=1}^m a_k 10^{2k} \mid m \geq 1, (a_1,\ldots,a_m) \in \{0,\ldots,9\}^m \}$

Comment: Ok, you are right again. Well done!

Comment: @Peter Thanks ! (and thanks for proof-checking)

Comment: Actually, you've got even more freedom: Instead of dividing in even and odd powers, you can use any set of natural numbers that is neither finite nor cofinite, and split into the powers from that set and the powers of its complement.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui Nice answer.